# (Kotlin) Setting a OnclickListener on a fragmentList Item

Tags: android, kotlin

I´m making a tabbed activity, one of the **fragments** has to show a list of elements, in this case a **cardview** with a few things inside. I have tried to set a **onClickListener** on the cardview itself but it doesn´t seem to work (the clicking part, not the app itself),thank you for reading ,this is my **onBind** and **inner class ViewHolder**:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = museus[position]
    holder.nom.text = item.nom
    holder.direccio.text = item.direccio
    holder.parentCardView.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
        Toast.makeText(MyApp.instance, "Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    }¨


    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val nom: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.museu_nom)
    val direccio: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.museu_direccio)
    val parentCardView: CardView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentCardView)
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I was able to set the onclickListener on the ViewHolder, Ichanged the contructor to have the activity context inside it.

```
class PreviewMuseoRecyclerViewAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PreviewMuseoRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val nom: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.museu_nom)
    val direccio: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.museu_direccio)
    //val parentCardView: CardView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentCardView)
    init {
        view.setOnClickListener{
            Log.i("hola","Funciona2")
            context?.startActivity(Intent(context, Mood::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Now i just need to pass a value from the viewHolder onto the next activity, since you dont assing them in this inner class im a bit lost on how to do it.

```
context?.startActivity(Intent(context, Mood::class.java).putExtra("id", ?? ))
```

Comment: Try changing `MyApp.instance` to `v.context` in `makeToast()`

Comment: tried it, and it didn´t work i dont think it has to do with the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
holder.parentCardView.setOnClickListener{
Toast.makeText(context, "Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
}
```

and you have to declare Context using the Primary constructor.
Example below.

```
class FragmentAdapter(private val context: Context, private val fragmentList: MutableList<Fragment?>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved part of my problem, however i cant get the information i need to the next activity, ill post the followup on the edit

Comment: Thanks, this solved part of my problem, i have a follow up question on my profile, thanks for the help so far. I have a problem creating a intent inside the onBind (startActivity() doesn´t work).

Comment: @AntonioSanjurjo Please do NOT change your post to ask another question. This seems to have answered your original question. Please set it as the accepted answer. As for your other problem, please post a new question.